# Circle made by canvas Arc is misbehaving in IE10 and fine in Chrome--confirm?

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

**[Edit: Sent bug report: received reply that closePath is required an arc-->circle drawings]**

So IE requires closePath on arcs that form circles but Chrome/FF let you go without:

```
context.beginPath();
context.arc(100,100,3,0,Math.PI*2,false);
context.closePath();
```

**End edit**

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

This code is supposed to simply display rows and columns of circles in html canvas.

Can anyone else confirm that this displays fine in Chrome and displays **weird** in IE?

If so, any ideas why?

I’m running IE version: 10.0.9200.16540.

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/P72NM/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var spacing=15;
    var linespacing=8;
    var radius=3;

    ctx.lineWidth=linespacing;
    ctx.fillStyle="maroon";

    ctx.strokeStyle="red";
    ctx.beginPath();
    for(var row=5;row<canvas.height;row+=spacing*3){
        for(var col=5;col<canvas.width;col+=spacing*3){
            ctx.arc(col,row, 4, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        }
    }    
    ctx.fill();


}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can confirm, but I can't explain why.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, I'll submit a bug report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to note that **Chrome is the incorrect one here.** IE10 and Firefox are following the specification properly.

It's more apparent in a simple example such as this:

```
ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255,0,0,.4)';

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(50,50,20,Math.PI*2, 0);
ctx.arc(50,150,20,Math.PI*2, 0);
ctx.arc(150,100,20,Math.PI*2, 0);

ctx.stroke();
ctx.fill();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZMKEG/

The results of such:

[image]

According to the specification, the `arc` command adds two points to a subpath and the arc between them. It does not close a subpath, and it **only** adds an implicit `moveTo` if it is at the start of the current path. IE and Firefox are doing the right thing here.

Chrome is (half-)assuming a kind of `moveTo` between the arc calls, but only for filling.

In other words, between several `arc` commands there should be straight lines, as Chrome correctly shows when `stroke()` is applied. Chrome is not respecting these lines for filling, and that's a bug.

Comment: Answer and +1: Very good point!  Now I mentally think of  arc(x,y,r,0,PI2,false) as a 360 degree arc with 2 overlapping (but separate) end-points.  One would have thought I would catch on faster given that **the command is called “arc” and not ”circle”** !!  Thanks again Simon—you’re always a source of good knowledge.