# Cannot draw line on Canvas with Firefox

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I have a simple canvas test and I don't seem to get it working on Firefox. I really get no error on JS console. Version is 17.0.4, will try on a newer version later. Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<SCRIPT>
var paint = false;
var canvas;
var cntxt;
var top;
var left;

function initialise() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas_1");
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", doMouseDown, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", doMouseUp, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", doMouseMove, false);
    cntxt = canvas.getContext("2d");
    cntxt.strokeStyle = '#ff0000';
    cntxt.lineWidth = 5;
    cntxt.lineCap = 'round';    
    rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    top = rect.top;
    left = rect.left;
}
function doMouseDown(event) {
    paint = true;  
    x = event.layerX;
    y = event.layerY;
    document.getElementById("value_x").innerHTML = x;
    document.getElementById("value_y").innerHTML = y;
    cntxt.moveTo(x-left, y-top);
    cntxt.beginPath();  
    cntxt.stroke();
}
function doMouseUp(event) {
    paint = false; 
    x = event.layerX;
    y = event.layerY;
    document.getElementById("value_x").innerHTML = x;
    document.getElementById("value_y").innerHTML = y;
    cntxt.lineTo(x-left+1, y-top+1);
    cntxt.stroke();
    cntxt.closePath();
}
function doMouseMove(event) {
  if(paint) {
    x = event.layerX;
    y = event.layerY;
    document.getElementById("value_x").innerHTML = x;
    document.getElementById("value_y").innerHTML = y;
    cntxt.lineTo(x-left, y-top);
    cntxt.stroke();     
  }
}
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY onLoad="initialise()">
<canvas width="400" height="400" id="canvas_1">
Canvas Tag not supported
</canvas>
<br>
Value x: <span id="value_x"></span>
<br>
Value y: <span id="value_y"></span>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

In MSIE it works fine (Version 9), but Firefox displays the coordinates properly in the span elements, but no line is drawn... I thought that using the layerX and layerY should have done the trick but they don't...

Thank you and regards

Comment: Seems to work just fine for me at http://jsfiddle.net/pyHYG/ (although with v20.0.1) Try `console.log`ing all the variables/events to see if they are as expected..

Comment: Well, I was able to find the problem that way... The top and left variables somehow are mapped to other objects, so I renamed them to topMargin and leftMargin and now it's working just fine... Thank you for the tip...

Comment: That is why you should not use globals... ;)

Comment: Good point, however it's just a small test that will be used for a demo, so I just need it working on the most popular browsers. I I happen to use this on a real implementation, I would do it differently...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Odd, but both Mozilla and Chrome don't like you using a variable called `top`.

It appears to be a reserved word relating to the `window`.

Change `top` to `canvasTop` and you should be fine.

**[edit: Chuckle--as you've Already Discovered!  Next time I read comments better!]**

You might also want to use clientX/clientY instead of layerX/layerY.

Here's code that works in IE,FF & Chrome:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<SCRIPT>
var paint = false;
var canvas;
var cntxt;
var canvastop;
var left;

function initialise() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas_1");
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", doMouseDown, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", doMouseUp, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", doMouseMove, false);
    cntxt = canvas.getContext("2d");
    cntxt.strokeStyle = '#ff0000';
    cntxt.lineWidth = 5;
    cntxt.lineCap = 'round';    
    rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    canvastop = rect.top;
    left = rect.left;
}
function doMouseDown(event) {
    paint = true;  
    x = event.clientX;
    y = event.layerY;
    document.getElementById("value_x").innerHTML = x;
    document.getElementById("value_y").innerHTML = y;
    cntxt.moveTo(x-left, y-canvastop);
    cntxt.beginPath();  
    cntxt.stroke();
}
function doMouseUp(event) {
    paint = false; 
    x = event.clientX;
    y = event.clientY;
    document.getElementById("value_x").innerHTML = x+"/"+left;
    document.getElementById("value_y").innerHTML = y+"/"+canvastop;
    cntxt.lineTo(x-left+1, y-canvastop+1);
    cntxt.stroke();
    cntxt.closePath();
}
function doMouseMove(event) {
  if(paint) {
    x = event.clientX;
    y = event.clientY;
    document.getElementById("value_x").innerHTML =  x+"/"+left;
    document.getElementById("value_y").innerHTML = y+"/"+canvastop;
    cntxt.lineTo(x-left, y-canvastop);
    cntxt.stroke();     
  }
}
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY onLoad="initialise()">
<canvas width="400" height="400" id="canvas_1">
Canvas Tag not supported
</canvas>
<br>
Value x: <span id="value_x"></span>
<br>
Value y: <span id="value_y"></span>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: It's fine, you wrote the full answer at the end... Now only one small question, how do I know the features supported by each browser? I didn't seem to find decent documentation on this issue. On the other hand, I was also fighting with Chrome, it didn't like the moveTo before the beginPath, so I had to change even more stuff to get it working properly.

Comment: Yes, canvas can be picky about beginPath/closePath across browsers (see my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995096/simple-canvas-code-misbehaving-in-ie10-and-fine-in-chrome-can-you-confirm)  The unofficial rules/regs/gotchas/pull-requests can be found in their verbose form here: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/